# Incorrect data array being returned : a ghost override?

Tags: php, function, static, overriding

There is a weird thing going on here.

A static function named `user_get_specific_data` of class `_user_profile` is called from some php file.

```
 /**
  * Get User Email
  */
$ud = _user_profile::user_get_specific_data(['username'], $body_params['user_id']);
```

The call lands at the right place.

```
/**
 * Reads the fields from the user table and returns as an array
 * @param array $data Associative array Parameters to read
 */
public static function user_get_specific_data($data,$userId){
    $output['status'] = false;
    $arr = self::query_get_specifc_fields($data, $userId); // calls a private static function
    if($arr['status']) {
        unset($arr['status']);
        $r = DB_Read($arr);
        if($r) { // BLOCK F
            $output['status'] = true;
            $output['data'] = $r[0];
        }

    }
    return $output;
}
```

On success, it will return an array that will resemble :

```
[
  'status' => true,
  'data' => [...] // array

]
```

So, I have debugged the code and everything goes fine in the function and the statement `return $output` when inspected (while debugging), contains the array it will return on success but when it does return and I inspect `$ud`, I see an array that looks like:

```
['status' => false]
```

Why is that? What happened? The code always enters `BLOCK F` but `$ud` always receives `false`! I am calling it a ghost override!!

**Important input:** If I comment `$output['status'] = false;` inside the function `user_get_specific_data` `$ud` always receives `null`. It seems to me like a scope problem.

In the following image, code enters the `BLOCK F` and `$r` contains an array, but its var_dump doesn't evaluate!

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of var_dump($r); Despite what you say, I am under the impression that php never execute Block F.

Comment: @vincenth Updated with a snapshot. `$r` prints an array in watch but var_dump doesn't evaluate

Comment: var_dump is not supposed to return anything, it just dump what you pass as a parameter.